# How to insert NULL into Snowflake string column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the pandas_tools package to write data to my Snowflake table.

```
create table TEST_TBL(
    ID integer,
    VALUE string
)
```

```
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.connector import pandas_tools as pt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': [1, 2],
                        'VALUE': ['test', None]
                       })

# assume everything else is set up previously
pt.write_pandas(conn=conn, 
                df=df, 
                table_name=table_name,
                database=database,
                schema=schema)
```

Using `write_pandas()`, instead of inserting a NULL value in the VALUE column where ID=2 (which is what I would expect to happen with a python NoneType), it instead writes the literal string "None" into the table.

[image: Snowflake table]

I have tried it with `np.nan` as well and that also writes a literal string "NaN" into the column. How do I get it to insert a NULL value into the record?

*Sample of expected null outputs from another table.*

[image: Sample data from another table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be correct.

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.connector import pandas_tools as pt

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(**connection_parameters)
cursor = conn.cursor()
database = connection_parameters['database']
schema = connection_parameters['schema']
table_name = 'TEST_TBL'

sql = f'create table {table_name}(ID integer,VALUE string)'
cursor.execute(sql)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': [1, 2],
                        'VALUE': ['test', None]
                       })

# assume everything else is set up previously
pt.write_pandas(conn=conn, 
                df=df, 
                table_name=table_name,
                database=database,
                schema=schema)

sql = f'select * from {table_name}'
cursor.execute(sql)
for (ID, VALUE) in cursor:
   print('ID: {0}, VALUE: {1}'.format(ID, VALUE))
```

```
ID: 1, VALUE: test
ID: 2, VALUE: None
```

[image]

Comment: Would it have made a difference if the value started out as a valid string? Essentially my null data comes in initially as strings of 'NaN', and what I did was do a `df.replace(np.nan, None)` which then ends up writing 'None' into the db instead. I thought it was due to how Snowflake converts NoneType in python, but that doesn't seem to be the case from your results.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct as the issue turns out to be something completely different. Because my table is in long format, I was doing a `df['VALUE'].astype.str` to force all values to string before it was written. Turns out that was unnecessary, and was actually what caused the problem. It decided to convert the NoneType into a string value as well. Leaving this here for anyone who makes the same mistake as I did.